# How to fix disabled excel macro file, when workbook is protected with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

When I open macro enabled excel file, the macro becomes disabled in protected workbook (VBA code does not run). But when protection is removed from the workbook, the macro file becomes enabled and the VBA code runs fine.

Is there is any way to protect the workbook and also to run VBA code in macro file simultaneously.

`Sub test()
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("mypassward")
' my vba code
ActiveWorkbook.Protect ("mypassward")
End Sub`

Comment: Are you sure you're not running into some error because of protection and suppressing the errors?  Without seeing your code, that's a safe assumption.  I'd suggest sharing the rest of your code.

Comment: This post may provide you some direction and a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932254/macros-dont-work-when-sheet-is-protected-running-macro-returns-run-time-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macros don't work when sheet is protected. Running macro returns run-time error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932254/macros-dont-work-when-sheet-is-protected-running-macro-returns-run-time-error)