# Excel Run Macro button with password protection

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook is passwordprotected and consists of unlocked cells for input and ane button for PDF print. Due to the password protection of the sheets the PDF print button doesn't work.

I have tried with the following earlier questions and answers. Yet it says that my entered password is wrong(!)

[Macros don't work when sheet is protected. Running macro returns run-time error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932254/macros-dont-work-when-sheet-is-protected-running-macro-returns-run-time-error)

```
Sub ButtonClick()

UnprotectAll

'Some stuff here

ProtectAll

End Sub

Private Const yourPassword As String = "ThePassWord"

Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub

Sub ProtectAll()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Next sh
End Sub
```

I get the

> error "1004".
>   The password you supplied is not correct.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the correct password?

Comment: @TimStack Yes I believe I had. But what is "the correct password"? Several users should be able to use this workbook and button.

Comment: AFAIK *you* are the one who locked the wb, so you should know the password. The user does not need to know the password as long as your code unlocks the wb with the correct password

Comment: @TimStack Great! It is the same pawssword. I have relocated the password string and it solves the error 1004. Yet all sheets are unprotected after running the script.

Comment: Well that is exactly what you coded. You want VBA *not* to do what you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` as first line in **every** module and worksheet code! This ensures you don't run into a not declared local scope variable `yourPassword` which then is empty.

   I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.
2. Make sure you unprotect (manually) all your sheets using your password.
3. Define your new desired password as constant in a module

   ```
    Private Const yourPassword As String = "ThePassWord"
   ```
4. Use this constant for your `.Protect`/`.Unprotect`

   ```
    sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
   ```
5. Then run your code again.

Comment: Thank you! I Just realized that. The problem was that `Private Const yourPassword As String = "ThePassWord"` was located in the middle of the module and not in the very beginning.

Comment: @SimonJ Anyway activate `Option Explicit`. It would have thrown a warning.

Comment: I just did. It didn't throw a warning. But all sheets are now unprotected after running the script?

Comment: @SimonJ strange I thought it should. • If you run `ProtectAll` all should be protected. Or what was your question? Note that `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has the focus (is on top) but `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is running in.

Comment: I run `ProtectAll` just before my `End Sub` at the `ButtonClick()`. Yet it leaves all sheets unprotected and whole workbook too.

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. If it doesn't work go throug your code step by step using F8 and see what happens.

Comment: `ProtectAll` works fine just by it self. I have tried to move it around in the script but it gets more buggy than else. I belive it should be before `Exit Sub` and/or the `ExitHandler`?

Comment: @SimonJ well that's getting a way beyond your original question now. Please ask a new question if you have a new problem and post your code in the new question. We are not able to answer follow up questions in comments that are not the original question. • But of course you should make sure it runs (even in case of error).

Comment: I've tried another approach and created a sub for the button only which calls for `UnprotectAll`, then `MainRutine`, then `ProtectAll`. It is the `Method 'Protect' of object '_Worksheet failed` that comes as a error 1004 now

Comment: @SimonJ Again: Please ask a new question and include your code in that new question, we cannot answer this in comments here.